# Drupal : Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in database.inc on line 187

Tags: drupal

This is error occured me for my old Drupal site and it tooks my around hour of time, to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Create php.ini file in public_html folder of your site and below lines to enable the required extensions:

```
extension="pdo.so"
extension="pdo_mysql.so"
```